# Bootstrap modal does show correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show a modal window on demand by click of a button.

In the `<head>...</head>` tags, I have the following:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In the `<body>...</body>` I have the following definition of the modal markup:

```
<div id="slideInfoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="slideInfoTitle" class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="slideInfoBody" class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript button click handler looks like this:

```
// Method to show current slide info
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
        $('#slideInfoModal').modal();
    });
});
```

When the code runs, the modal appears like this:

[image]

It's supposed to look like this (as per [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h)):

[image]

Any idea why it looks `wrong`?

I do have the following custom css stylesheet loaded: http://pastebin.com/6f9SUsiv

Could any of this be breaking bootstrap modal? These styles are required for the page I am working with.

Comment: Its working with me. Can you please create a JSbin with the whole issue?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. I tested it on my end and it is actually working. You may have done something with your css that may have interferred with the boostrap's modal css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working code snippet of the code in your question, and it works both with and without the pastebin CSS.

Without the jQuery link, there is no modal functionality at all.

The image of the non-working modal that you included in your question suggests a CSS problem. But perhaps this code snippet will be helpful in finding the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
    $('#slideInfoModal').modal();
  });
});
```

```css
html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; }
        #imageView { height: 100%; background-size: cover; display: none; }
        #progressViewDisplay { padding: 10% 60px 20px 60px; text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; }
  #slideShowControls { position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 20px; width: 100%; height: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: right; display: none; }

.meter {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 60px 60px 60px;
    background: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.meter > span:after,
.animate > span > span {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animate > span:after {
    display: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 50px 50px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 50px 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="slideInfoModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 id="slideInfoTitle" class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="slideInfoBody" class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="slideInfo">Show</button>
```

Comment: the problem turned out to be really weird. my modal html was below, therefore it did not work. I have replicated the issue here: http://pastebin.com/dtjV4kEq (to fix this, i had to move the modal div after `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery, and what you show here, you don't link to jQuery.
Try add this to your head-section if not already done:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```